# NULLs get erroneously imported as empty strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  I am importing a pipe-delimited text file via the wizard (i.e., not with BULK INSERT) into a destination table.  I am not specifying a text-qualifier (because there should not be any pipes in the values themselves).  The file imports into the table properly, but I noticed that NULLs are transformed into empty strings (which I do not want).  I do not have a transformation specified, and the columns in error are nullable.  Can somebody please explain why this is happening and how to mitigate it?  I do not have access to BIDS, and I cannot run BULK INSERT statements.

Comment: Representing a `NULL` (which is the *absence* of a value) is kinda hard in a text file.... if you have two pipe delimiters after one another ( `||` ), then you really *have* an empty string between those two - not `NULL` ....

Comment: When I import the file into Excel (to do some modifications to the data), save the Excel file, and then import into my destination tables, I don't run into this problem.  So, when reading from an Excel file, SQL Server must interpret empty strings as NULLs.  But, when importing into the destination tables straight from a text file, it interprets empty strings as empty strings.  Is there not a way to force SQL to always interpret empty strings as NULLs?

Comment: I just ran another test case.  If the import is straight from a text file, not only do empty strings stay as empty strings (i.e., they don't get imported as NULL), but strings of any length of white spaces also get imported as empty strings.  So, it seems that passing the file through Excel first is the only solution.